# What's the official way to escape a comment (#) in Gherkin/Cucumber?

Tags: regex, escaping, cucumber, gherkin

I'm writing a Gherkin feature file, *e.g.*

```
Given the following # data
And   I open the page
Then  all fields are correct
```

I don't want the `#` in the above to be interpreted as a comment, which would remove the `data` afterward.

What's the official Gherkin way to escape the `#` symbol, if any?  I've looked at the [official documentation](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin), and this [guide](http://behat.readthedocs.org/en/v2.5/guides/1.gherkin.html) and neither seems to answer my question.

I've tried using the invented HTML entity `&hash;` in my parser, which works and is easy to write a regular expression for. If I were to use the official HTML entity `&#35;` or escape with a backslash (*e.g.* `\#`) either option would itself include the `#` symbol and make parsing harder. In the end, however, I'd rather use the official method, if possible, even if it's a bit harder to implement.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The grammar used in the ruby and java implementations can be found here: https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin/blob/master/ragel/lexer_common.rl.erb

It does not look like there is any escaping defined for comments, but since gherkin is a line-based syntax I would not expect a comment to actually be recognized inline after a step. Contrary to the syntax highlighting in

```
Given the following # data
When I open the page
```

I would expect the content of the step to contain everything including the "# data" part.

That is also my interpretation of the description at https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin#gherkin-syntax

> Comment **lines** are allowed anywhere in the file. They begin with zero or more spaces, followed by a hash sign (#) and some amount of text.

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that definition, but I hadn't fully considered the implications. So any particular line is either a comment or it is not. Works for me!